# How to use traits in Laravel 5.4.18?

Tags: php, laravel, traits

I need an example of where to exactly create the file, to write to it, and how to use the functions declared in the trait. **I use Laravel Framework 5.4.18**

*-I have not altered any folder in the framework, everything is where it corresponds-*

From already thank you very much.

Comment: Traits are a language feature, not a framework feature. So http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php should be everything you need.

Comment: @MateuszSip Yes I know. But where do I put the file to work?

Comment: Are you aware of [namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php)? 
Just import your trait and use it, trait documentation says how to do that.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I have Create a Traits directory in my `Http` directory with a Trait called `BrandsTrait.php`

and use it like:

```
use App\Http\Traits\BrandsTrait;

class YourController extends Controller {

    use BrandsTrait;

    public function addProduct() {

        //$brands = Brand::all();

        // $brands = $this->BrandsTrait();  // this is wrong
        $brands = $this->brandsAll();
    }
}
```

Here is my BrandsTrait.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Traits;

use App\Brand;

trait BrandsTrait {
    public function brandsAll() {
        // Get all the brands from the Brands Table.
        $brands = Brand::all();

        return $brands;
    }
}
```

**Note:** Just like a normal function written in a certain `namespace`, you can use `traits` as well

Comment: I get the error `BadMethodCallException in Controller.php line 82:
Method [BrandsTrait] does not exist.`

Comment: Note that this is not the intended usage of a trait. In the way that it is being used here, this would be best used as a `repository interface`. A trait should be something that is intended to be re-used across multiple different controllers/models.

Answer (score 9):

**Trait description:**

Traits are a mechanism for code reuse in single inheritance languages such as PHP. A Trait is intended to reduce some limitations of single inheritance by enabling a developer to reuse sets of methods freely in several independent classes living in different class hierarchies. The semantics of the combination of Traits and classes is defined in a way which reduces complexity and avoids the typical problems associated with multiple inheritance and Mixins.

**The solution**

Make a directory in your App, named `Traits`

Create your own trait in `Traits` directory ( file: Sample.php ):

```
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

trait Sample
{
    function testMethod()
    {
        echo 'test method';
    }
}
```

Then use it in your own controller:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Traits\Sample;

class MyController {
    use Sample;
}
```

Now the `MyController` class has the `testMethod` method inside.

You can change the behavior of trait methods by overriding them it in `MyController` class:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Traits\Sample;

class MyController {
    use Sample;

    function testMethod()
    {
        echo 'new test method';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Let's look at an example trait:

```
namespace App\Traits;

trait SampleTrait
{
    public function addTwoNumbers($a,$b)
    {
        $c=$a+$b;
        echo $c;
        dd($this)
    }
}
```

Then in another class, just import the trait and use the function with `this` as if that function was in the local scope of that class:

```
<?php

namespace App\ExampleCode;

use App\Traits\SampleTrait;

class JustAClass
{
    use SampleTrait;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->addTwoNumbers(5,10);
    }
}
```