# Cannot create custom Traits in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

For some reason with Laravel 5.5.36, I cannot create a Trait that is recognisable by the Laravel framework.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\LedaAuth\Authenticate\LoginController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use LedaAuth\Authenticate\LedaAuthenticate;

class LgStfController extends LoginController
{

    use LedaAuthenticate;
    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/dashboard';

...
```

The Laravel threw an error saying `"Trait 'Something\Authenticate\LedaAuthenticate' not found".` Eventhough the my tree is

```
- Controllers
    + Auth
    - LedaAuth
        - Authenticate
            > LedaAuthenticate.php
            > LoginController.php
    > LgStfController.php
```

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: there is a typo in your tree, `LedaAuthenicate` instead of `LedaAuthenticate`

Comment: @Liora My bad, I fixed that. I am using PhpStorm, so it helps me all the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any one who might encounter the same problem. I was able to fix the problem by creating a folder name `Traits` in the `Http` folder.

```
- App
  - Http
    - Controllers
    + Auth
    - LedaAuth
        - Authenticate
            > LoginController.php
        > LgStfController.php
    - Traits
       - LedaAuth
           > LedaAuthenticate.php
```

How I thought of this was first inspired by [How to use traits in Laravel 5.4.18?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43433350/how-to-use-traits-in-laravel-5-4-18/43433384]) question.

Then looking through the reason why, I believe that the laravel autoload function follows the PSR-4 system and classes are refered through in `use Namespace\SubNamespace\Classname` except for `Illuminate\Something\SomeClass` where the Illuminate doesn't have to be the first subfoleder the laravel project folder unlike other class declarations like `use App\Http\Controllers\SomeController`.

So this time, when creating the `Trait` folder, I refered it as 
`use App\Http\Traits\LedaAuth\LedaAuthenticate`.

So the new file is re-written as;

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\LedaAuth;

use App\Http\Controllers\LedaAuth\Authenticate\LoginController;
use App\Http\Traits\LedaAuth\LedaAuthenticate;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class LgStfController extends LoginController
{

    use LedaAuthenticate;
    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/dashboard';

...
```

I hope that helps.