# Public functions relating to a custom page in Filament v3

Tags: function, laravel-filament

I am trying to code a custom function that will be called by different actions from multiple custom pages. In the traditional Laravel framework, I would have located these in a Services file under App\Services. However, when I create a Services file with the normal __construct() on the pages file, I get an error that the incorrect number of arguments are being passed.

I created a function in a Service as follows:

```
<?php


namespace App\Services;

class TripService

{

    public function test(){

        dd('yes');

    }


}
```

Then, on a custom page called LocationVolumeView, I added the normal construction:

```
class LocationVolumeView extends Page implements HasForms, HasTable
{

    private $tripService;

   public function __construct (TripService $tripService)
   {
       $this->tripService = $tripService;
   }
```

Then, later on the same page, I have an action that calls on this function:

```
->action(function (array $data,): void {


                        $this->tripService->test();


                    })
```

Unfortunately I get the error:

Too few arguments to function App\Filament\Pages\LocationVolumeView::__construct(), 0 passed in /Users/iainreynard/Code/TMS_ver2/vendor/livewire/livewire/src/Features/SupportPageComponents/SupportPageComponents.php on line 212 and exactly 1 expected

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to some outside help, the following answer works:

1. Because a custom page is just a live-wire component, the way to solve this is to use traits. In this way, functions can be added to the page
2. Useful link: [Using Traits in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43433350/how-to-use-traits-in-laravel-5-4-18)